# Angularjs generating link inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I need to process some parameters inside a controller and generate a link to a template. I cannot figure out how I try to pass assign `{{url}}`

```
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('{{url}}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">open</button>
```

http://www.someurl.com/someservice.php?param=param&anotherparam=another

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-click` without interpolation `{{}}` in it.

**Markup**

```
<button class="button" type="button" ng-click="window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
   open
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call angular code inside js `onclick`. you must use `ng-click` instead.

```
<button class="button" ng-click="window.open('{{url}}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">open</button>
```

Comment: can i detect the current platform into the template to show one button to android and ios and another to windowsphone? using ionic.Platform.device() ?